# Python coding environment

Tags: python, scripting

Blender is said to have perfect Python scripting capabilities. I just cannot find an environment, where I could try it all. Can you give an advise for the noob?

I have a problem with defining an environment for python coding. Once I complained about inability to use keys to select the current command line the command line or even delete it, IRC advised that command line is bad, especially because I also should not define any functions in it. I should better use the Text Editor instead.

However, I have discovered that I cannot run the Text Editor-defined scripts in the command line. Basically, I should forget about the command line and do everything in the Text Editor. Fortunately, it has the Run Script button. However, it is very boring to save every script before running. I better used external editor if I need to save the file before running it anyway. It also does not display me the errors. How can I program anything without seeing the errors. It says that my error msg was printed somewhere into unknown console. I came back to the command line but its view is too tiny. Can I make it in another window to switch easily between the 3D scene and the pycommand line? Probably, you have a better advise to make the operational python environment.

I hoped that I can store the successul lines of code in external editor and fiddler them into the console. But the following lines

```
for o in D.objects: o.select = True ; bpy.ops.object.delete()
earth = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()
```

succeed only if I paste them one-by-one and fail if I paste them two at once.

Answer (score 4):

I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Professional for Blender add-on development. It has debugging support (the Community edition does not) and limited auto-completion if you create auto-completion files for it with [this tool](https://github.com/mutantbob/pycharm-blender).

Here's a [tutorial and a Blender add-on](https://code.blender.org/2015/10/debugging-python-code-with-pycharm/) to connect Blender to the PyCharm debugger.

My workflow then is like this:

- Create an add-on and enable it in Blender. An add-on is basically a Python package you create inside a new package folder under `<version>\scripts\addons`.
- Edit its code in PyCharm.
- Reload the add-on in Blender with F8. This requires the `__init__.py` of the package to have a specific layout. Here are the bare bones I always use: I added some comments to the end of the lines and left several modules in there as an example (which you'd create accordingly in python code files inside the package directory):

  ```
  bl_info = {
      "name": "Title as it appears in settings",
      "description": "Smaller description below it",
      "author": "Your name",
      "version": (1, 0, 0), # A tuple of version numbers
      "blender": (2, 75, 0), # The minimum required Blender version
      "location": "File > Import-Export", # Where it will be located. These strings are hard-code in Blender
      "warning": "This add-on is under development.", # A warning with a yellow triangle if you want.
      "wiki_url": "https://github.com/Syroot/io_scene_kcl/wiki", # Link to a wiki
      "tracker_url": "https://github.com/Syroot/io_scene_kcl/issues", # Link to an issue tracker
      "support": "COMMUNITY", # Probably just COMMUNITY since you're not an official developer etc.
      "category": "Import-Export" # Also hardcode
  }

  # Reload the package modules when reloading add-ons in Blender with F8.
  if "bpy" in locals():
      import importlib
      if "log"       in locals(): importlib.reload(log)
      if "binary_io" in locals(): importlib.reload(binary_io)
      if "kcl_file"  in locals(): importlib.reload(kcl_file)
      if "importing" in locals(): importlib.reload(importing)
      if "editing"   in locals(): importlib.reload(editing)
      if "exporting" in locals(): importlib.reload(exporting)

  import bpy
  from . import log
  from . import binary_io
  from . import importing
  from . import editing
  from . import exporting

  def register():
      bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
      # Importing
      bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(importing.ImportOperator.menu_func_import) # Add menu entry to File > Import
      # Editing
      bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_similar.append(editing.KclSelectSimilar.menu_func) # Add custom properties to a mesh
      bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(editing.scene_update_post_handler) # Listen to global Blender-wide events
      # Exporting
      bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(exporting.ExportOperator.menu_func_export) # Add menu entry to File > Export

  def unregister(): # Basically just undo the stuff done in register()
      bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
      # Importing
      bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(importing.ImportOperator.menu_func_import)
      # Editing
      bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_similar.remove(editing.KclSelectSimilar.menu_func)
      bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.remove(editing.scene_update_post_handler)
      # Exporting
      bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(exporting.ExportOperator.menu_func_export)

  # Register the package modules when Blender runs this script.
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      register()
  ```
- Optionally, set breakpoints and connect Blender to the remote debugger of PyCharm.
- Call operators the add-on defines, test the stuff it adds.
- Fix errors, reload with F8, rinse, repeat.

You can find some samples of add-ons of me in [my GitHub repos](https://github.com/Syroot) (check out those named with the `io_scene_*` name prefix).

Comment: Just a minor point, I ran into a problem in PyCharm on Windows where I could not create a new project "from source" from the addon folder created at `<version>\scripts\addons`. PyCharm would just do nothing. Figured out that I actually needed to run PyCharm as Administrator.